# PHP strstr equivalent in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have one simple table "localization" with  two fields (city , street).

I want to get only one column "place" but I can't find strstr equivalent in MySQL.

My Query should do something like this:

```
SELECT IF(stristr($city, 'earth'),city,street) as place 
FROM `localization` 
WHERE city LIKE ('%krak%') OR street LIKE ('%krak%');
```

Of course **stristr($city, 'earth')** is PHP convention , but I wrote this to explain what the problem is.

I hope you know what I mean :)

Comment: So why don't you try google for "strstr equivalent sql" ?

Comment: what about the route of least resistance? fetch the whole result from the database and elaborate it inside your application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the Regular expresion in mysql. Your query will be:

```
SELECT IF(city like '%krak%',city,street) as place 
    FROM `localization` 
    WHERE city LIKE ('%krak%') OR street LIKE ('%krak%');
```

Try above query.

Comment: Thanks - it works for me (with small corrections)

Comment: it works well with : IF(city like '%krak%',city,street) as place

Comment: @Adam my pleasure to help you. I will modify my post as suggested by you. and please accept the answer.

Answer (score 4):

As found with a quick google search:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(field_name, instr(field_name, 'needle'), LENGTH(field_name)) AS result FROM table
```

From here:

http://www.coolsnippets.net/browse/id/18

So, in your case:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING($city, instr($city, 'earth'), LENGTH($city)) AS place
FROM `localization` 
WHERE city LIKE ('%krak%') OR street LIKE ('%krak%');
```

Comment: Really thanks for this clear info.

Comment: select id,response_data,SUBSTRING(response_data,instr(response_data,'rrnumber'),27) as rrn_p
from t_cardinfo where 1

Answer (score 2):

Edit: rereading your question, your testing if earth exists in city, using a conditional, so you're not really using `stristr` for how it is intended.

```
SELECT IF(LOCATE('earth',`city`),`city`,`street`) AS `place`
```

`LOCATE` will return 0 if not found.

---

Use `LOCATE` and `SUBSTRING`. See [MySQL String Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) reference. Remember `SUBSTRING` is not 0-indexed, instead the index starts at 1, and `LOCATE` returns the index >= 1 if found, or 0 if not found.

Snippet:

```
SELECT IF(SUBSTRING(`city`,LOCATE('earth',`city`)) AS `place`
FROM `localization`
WHERE `city` LIKE ('%krak%') OR `street` LIKE ('%krak%');
```

Also, don't mix your backtick usage, either use them on everything or not at all (I prefer the former).